# Fullcalendar visualization error with resources and dynamic events in agendaDay

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a problem when viewing events within dynamic resources. Mi code is this and resources and events are filled correctly. The resources are filled before the events.

```
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                defaultDate: '2017-07-27',
                resources: function(callback, start, end, timezone) {
                    $scope.getResourcesFullCalendar(start, end, timezone, function(resourceObjects) {
                        debugger;
                        callback(resourceObjects);
                    });             
                },
                events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ){
                    $scope.getEventsFullCalendar(start, end, timezone, function(eventsObjects) {
                        callback(eventsObjects);
                    });
                },
                allDaySlot: false,
                nowIndicator : true,
                minTime: "08:00:00",
                maxTime: "22:00:00",
                editable: true,
                selectable: true
});
```

When resources and events are filled by the callback function, It looks like this.

[View error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmS7F.png)

I would like to know what is the problem that looks bad sometimes, because at other times it shows well, or if I change day and return to the day is already shown correctly.

[View ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TePE6.png)

Please see if you can help me, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: is this occurring with identical event/resource data every time? Or is it different data which causes the issue to appear? If so you should give examples of data which works, and data which doesn't, for comparison purposes.

Comment: Also, you say "The resources are filled before the events". How do you know this? Are the callbacks synchronous? If they both fetch the data via ajax, then they aren't normally synchronous, so you can't rely on one to complete first. Having said that, I think fullCalendar copes with this possibility, since it explicitly encourages to populate them via ajax feeds. I doubt this is related to your issue. What could be an issue is if one call or the other is failing, or returning incorrect data.

Comment: The problem always happens with the same data. I think the problem is because of the resources because if I put these static, if it looks good.

Just what I do to make it work well is to advance one day and then go back and look correctly as in the picture.

But if I refresh the screen is when it loads badly.

Comment: By means of a timeout in the events, debugging the code, it is filled before the resources that the events, so there should not be the problem. The call is not failing and the data structure is correct

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way to load the fullcalendar, first I got the resources and events through ajax calls and then when I had all the information, I loaded the fullcalendar and it worked correctly.